# Variable creation inside an OracleDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, sql

It's been helpfully suggested that I don't have to keep writing

> dr["building_id"].ToString()

in the code snipped below.  That I only need to put the above into a variable, i.e, sBldgID, and use the latter subsequently.

```
...
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn)) {
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (dr.Read()) {
         if (dr["building_id"].ToString() != " " && dr["building_id"].ToString() != "" && dr["building_id"].ToString() != null) {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(path, true)) {
               IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == dr["building_id"].ToString());
               WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheets.FirstOrDefault().Id);

...
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
```

Good advice.  How do I do it?  How do I use dr.Read() that way before the while loop starts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the advice was pretty clear:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn)) {
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (dr.Read()) {

         string buildingId = dr["building_id"].ToString(); // <-- chache building id

         if (buildingId != " " && buildingId != "" && buildingId != null) {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(path, true)) {
               IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == buildingId);
               WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheets.FirstOrDefault().Id);

...
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Simply chache the `dr["building_id"].ToString()` in a local variable (like `building_id` here).

Comment: Doesn't even that itself keep getting performed every time it loops?  Or is that pretty much the shortest route?

Comment: @ni37osllb yes of course...every `dr.Read()` switches to the next row in the result, and I assume you want to use the `building_id` of this next row. Or is this building id the same in all rows?

Comment: For better readability I suggest using `if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(buildingId))` instead of 3 comparisons.

Comment: @derpirscher I'd agree, but don't know OP's detailed requirements, maybe it's not the same

Comment: René, building_id is different for other rows, thanks.  And thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming building_id is numeric, I instead recommend you write:

```
if (! System.Convert.IsDbNull(dr["building_id"]))
```

If it's text, I'd recommend this:

```
if (! System.Convert.IsDbNull(dr["building_id"]) && ! String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr["building_id"].ToString()))
```

This is how we check for nulls, blanks and whitespace.